# Работа с собственными моделями

Tags: qt5

Изучаю Qt по книге Макс Шлее Qt 5.3 профессиональное программирование С++, стр. 220
Как мне добавить img в ячейку моей модели :public QAbstractTableModel
ведь методы data() and setData() перегружены.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого необходимо в переопределяемом методе `data()` добавить

```
if(role==Qt::DecorationRole)
return QIcon(/*Path to the image*/);
```